# Execute multiple queries in parallel with Dapper

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dapper

I trying to execute three similar SQL queries in parallel using Dapper and stored procedures to get three similar results after all queries are completed.

Here is my code:

```
public class SomeReport
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeContext"].ToString();
    public ReportStatus ReportStatus { get; set; }
    public long NetworkServerTime { get; set; }
    public string ReportLastErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public RowSet[] FirstRowSet { get; set; }
    public RowSet[] SecondRowSet { get; set; }
    public RowSet[] ThirdRowSet { get; set; }

    public Report()
    {
        NetworkServerTime = 0;
        ReportStatus = ReportStatus.NotCreated;
    }


    public async Task GetReportDataAsync(ReportParameters parameters)
    {
        DynamicParameters requestParameters = new DynamicParameters();
        requestParameters.Add("@sinceDateFilter", parameters.SinceDate?.Date, DbType.DateTime);
        requestParameters.Add("@untilDateFilter", parameters.UntilDate?.Date, DbType.DateTime);
        requestParameters.Add("@countryId", parameters.CountryId, DbType.Int32);

        ReportLastErrorMessage = null;

        Task allTasks = null;
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        try
        {
            var firstTask = GetRows("[dbo].[GET_Report_FirstRowSet]", requestParameters);
            var secondTask =
                GetRows("[dbo].[GET_Report_SecondRowSet]", requestParameters);
            var thirdTask =
                GetRows("[dbo].[GET_Report_ThirdRowSet]", requestParameters);

            allTasks = Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask, thirdTask);

            FirstRowSet = await firstTask;
            SecondRowSet = await secondTask;
            ThirdRowSet = await thirdTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ReportStatus = ReportStatus.Error;
            ReportLastErrorMessage = allTasks?.Exception?.InnerExceptions.Last().Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ReportStatus != ReportStatus.Error)
            {
                ReportStatus = ReportStatus.Success;
                NetworkServerTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }

        }
        stopWatch.Reset();
    }

    private async Task<RowSet[]> GetRows(string procName, DynamicParameters parameters)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            RowSet[] rowsSet;

            try
            {
                var sqlString = string.Concat(procName, " @sinceDateFilter, @untilDateFilter, @countryId");
                var query = await conn.QueryAsync<RowSet>(sqlString, parameters, commandTimeout: 500);
                rowsSet = query.ToArray();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlEx)
            {
                rowsSet = new RowSet[0];
                throw;
            }

            return rowsSet;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I launch the debugger and SQL Server Profiler, I see that the queries are executed sequentially when creating the tasks corresponding to them.

How can I make queries start running at the same time and run in parallel?

Comment: You need to `await allTasks` first otherwise you aren't actually using the `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: To me that looks like it should already doing what you want (minor nit as per above comment aside) - what makes you think that they are actually sequential here, as opposed to just being reported sequentially because of how they were started? also: SqlClient may have opinions on what is/isn't valid here

Comment: @Marc if I use debugger and sql-profiler, I see that the first query in the profiler is executed when I am on the line of code `var firstTask = GetRows("[dbo].[GET_Report_FirstRowSet]", requestParameters);` but not when i am on the line of code `allTasks = Task.WhenAll (firstTask, secondTask, thirdTask);`

Comment: Hi, why do not use [multiple query](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multiple-results) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I use debugger and sql-profiler, I see that the first query in the profiler is executed when I am on the line of code `var firstTask = GetRows("[dbo].[GET_Report_FirstRowSet]", requestParameters);` but not when i am on the line of code `allTasks = Task.WhenAll (firstTask, secondTask, thirdTask);`

This is correct and normal. The way `async`/`await` works is that control is returned up the call-stack as soon as the first incomplete `await` happens, which in your case is the `await conn.QueryAsync<RowSet>`. However, you've still started the ball rolling *simply by calling the async method*. The operation isn't held at some pending state waiting for you to call `Task.WhenAll`, so we **expect** it to have already begun. `Task.WhenAll` doesn't do *anything* except aggregate the **await** step - it has no role in making things actually happen.

So: I suspect that everything is already working as expected, but simply: the tasks are reporting as *starting* in the order you have requested. Which is... exactly what we expect.

Answer (score -1):

Because all tasks already runs at the decleration time. When you assigned a task from returned GetRow method you alredy let it to start. Then using Task.WhenAll you created a new task that will return completed when all child task be completed. But you didn't wait this task also.

So you guaranteed the execution completion when the three task completion with await keyword.

If you can wrap all execution with a seperated Task you can call all of them parallel like that

```
var queries = new[] { 
    "[dbo].[GET_Report_FirstRowSet]", 
    "[dbo].[GET_Report_SecondRowSet]", 
    "[dbo].[GET_Report_ThirdRowSet]" 
};

var tasks = queries.Select(query => new Task(()=>{
    return GetRows(query, requestParameters);
})).ToArray();

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```